AnyLogic Transient phase Simulation Experiment
How can I set a transient phase of the simulation in AnyLogic so that it is not included in the statistics without changing the log entries?
For example, the first 100 orders should run through before the times are tracked

Manually :) AnyLogic is so flexible that there is no point in providing a warmup concept to users. This way you have full control.
For example, create an event with timeout=100 and make it eradicate any statistics collected so far:

Or use a statechart with state "warmup" and "running". Only log stats if in "running".
There are a million ways and it depends on how exactly you collect what stats :)

Ok, I followed your instructions and created an event. I have now tried to enter the following code from the Anylogic help in the "Action" field to delete the log:
try
{
getEngine().getModelDatabase().deleteExistingLogObjects(getDatabaseConnection());
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
error("Error occurred while deleting the model execution logs: " + e);
};
But after the execution of the event no new log is created, is there another possibility? or am I using the wrong function?

Just write into the log after time=100, no? Else, open a new issue and share details about what outputs you create where and when. Again: there are 1 million ways to "write outputs", so it always depends :)
